# How to check if a value exists in every forth or fifth row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Salary is usually paid monthly, but suppose I have weekly data:

```
id   week   salary
01     01      100
01     02        0
01     03        0
01     04        0
01     05        0
01     06      100
01     07        0
01     08        0
01     09        0
01     10      100
 ⁝       ⁝        ⁝ 
02     01        0
02     02        0
02     03        0
02     04      150
02     05        0
02     06        0
02     07        0
02     08        0
02     09        0
02     10        0
```

Since months are roughly 4.5 weeks, how can I make a binary employment column to check if the individual is employed (or has received salary in the next 4 or 5 weeks):

```
id   week   salary   employed
01     01      100          1
01     02        0          1
01     03        0          1
01     04        0          1
01     05        0          1
01     06      100          1
01     07        0          1
01     08        0          1            
01     09        0          1
01     10      100          1
 ⁝       ⁝        ⁝           ⁝
02     01        0          1
02     02        0          1
02     03        0          1
02     04      150          1
02     05        0          0
02     06        0          0 
02     07        0          0
02     08        0          0
02     09        0          0
02     10        0          0
```

Individuals `01` and `02` are paid monthly, so we expect them to have been employed for the past 5 weeks if they are paid in a given week.

Edit: I have removed individual `03` to simplify the question.

Comment: Have you tried `rolling` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html and then appling `any` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rolling window (of size 4 or 5 in your case) using `rolling` and check if the max value of the window is greater 0.

```py
df["employed"] = df["salary"].iloc[::-1].rolling(5, min_periods=0).max().astype(bool)
```

**Some explanations:**

- Since `rolling` creates a window backwards, you first have to revert the order of the DataFrame by applying `iloc[::-1]` before applying `rolling` to create a forward window (of size 5 in your case). So that would translate to a paycheck at the end of the month and therefore an employment the 5 weeks before the paycheck (like in your example).
- The `astype(bool)` converts a number to `True` if it's bigger than 0 and to `False` if it's 0. If you need it as integer (0 or 1) as in your question you can append `.astype(int)` to the expression.